# ffmpeg - zoompan causing stretching

Tags: ffmpeg

I have two images as input, both are 1600x1066. I am vertically stacking them. Then I am drawing a box and vertically stacking that box under both of the image. Inside of the box I write text, then I output a video that is 1080x1920. Everything works well, until I use zoompan to zoom in on the images, I get a weird behavior (see images included below). basically all input images including the box stretchs (shrink) vertically and no longer fit the entire height of the video which is 1920.

The command (removed some drawtext commands from it):

```
-filter_complex 
"color=s=1600x1066:color=blue, drawtext=fontfile=font.otf: text='My Text':fontcolor=white: fontsize=30: x=50: y=50[box]; 
[0]scale=4000x4000,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=125:s=1600x1066[z0];
[1]scale=4000x4000,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0015,1.5)':x='iw/2-(iw/zoom/2)':y='ih/2-(ih/zoom/2)':d=125:s=1600x1066[z1];
[z0][z1][box]vstack=inputs=3"
```

How do I fix this? I want to zoom in without stretching the images.

Video before using zoompan: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTBto.jpg

Video after using zoompan: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7faNn.png

Comment: Three images of 1066 height = 3198. Width is 1600. Ratio (1080/1920) != ratio (1600/3198)

Comment: Ok, I just figured out that the problem was this "scale=4000x4000", but without this the video would jiggle while zooming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the scaling done before the zoompan ("scale=4000x4000") to remove the jiggly zoom effect. the scaling ration was not equal to the ratio of the image.

Ratio of image: 1600/1066 = 1.5
Ratio of scaling: 4000/4000 = 1

So scaling had to be changed to 6000/4000 = 1.5, which solved the problem.